# php terminology: difference between getters and public methods?

Tags: php, oop, methods, terminology, getter

My question is more about terminology then technicalities (or is it?).

What's the difference between a getter method and a public method in a class? Are they one in the same or is there a distinction between them?

I ask because I'm trying to learn best coding practices and this area seems grey to me. I was commenting my code out and noticed I had a big section called "Getters" and another big section called "Public Methods" and then I was like... "what's the diff?!".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple terms, a getter in PHP is simply a method that allows other parts of your code to **access a certain class property**.

For example:

```
<?php

class Person {
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    // Getter
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$bob = new Person('Bob');
echo $bob->getName(); // Bob

?>
```

A method may not necessarily be designed to just return a property though; you can create other methods so that your class can **do funky things**.

To expand on the above example, let's give the `Person` class a method called `say()`, and give it a function/method parameter representing what to say:

```
    public function say($what) {
        printf('%s says "%s"', $this->name, $what);
    }
```

And call it after we create an object out of the class:

```
$bob = new Person('Bob');
echo $bob->getName(), "\n"; // Bob
$bob->say('Hello!');        // Bob says "Hello!"
```

Notice that inside the `say()` method I refer to `$this->name`. It's OK, since the `$name` property is found in the same class. The purpose of a getter (and its corresponding setter if any) is to allow other parts of your code to access this property.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks for the excellent explanation.

Comment: Good info, your first example prints "<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access private property Person::$name in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>17</b><br />". Was this intentional?

Comment: @SSH This: I don't think so! Thanks for pointing it out. Better late than never.

Answer (score 1):

Getters are public methods that return the value of a private variable. In a similar vein, setters are public methods that allow modification or "setting" of a private variable.

Comment: To extend upon this: getters and setters are used to accomplish `data encapsulation`.

Answer (score 0):

Public methods can be updated from outside the class, and the class doesn't necessarily have to know about it.

A public getter or setter gives you more flexibility - i.e. when we try and read `$obj->$property`, the variable might not be *ready*. However, if we use `$obj->getSomething()` we can do anything to that variable, to make it ready,

The difference is that public getters generally return a private variable. This means the only way to get the state of a property from the object is to get it via a method, which may or may not do extra things.